# How to find return type of a method from an XML documentation file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I'm trying to write a console app that will generate documentation pages based on the XML documentation file Visual Studio generates. So here's the problem, look at the XML generated by Visual Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<assembly>
    <name>Assembly-CSharp</name>
</assembly>
<members>
    <member name="M:Utility.ScaleRange(System.Single,System.Single,System.Single,System.Single,System.Single)">
        <summary>
        Scales x from inA-inB to outA-outB
        </summary>
        <param name="_x">Value to scale</param>
        <param name="_inA">Input range min</param>
        <param name="_inB">Input range max</param>
        <param name="_outA">Output range min</param>
        <param name="_outB">Output range max</param>
        <returns>Scaled value</returns>
    </member>
</members>
</doc>
```

As you can see there's no way to know what *type* the method returns unless I write it in `<returns>` when commenting my code (which is something I don't want to do).

Is there a way to make VS output the type of the method? If not then I'm guessing I'm gonna have to use Reflection to help me out with this project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the expectation is that you *would* use reflection for that - there's a lot of information that's otherwise missing, including the parameter types and modes. The XML file is meant to complement the reflection-based information, I believe.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yeah I was thinking that... But you can know the parameter types (`System.Single` is the same as float) and that's about it, I think `out`, `ref` and default values aren't outputted in the XML file...

Comment: Whoops, had missed that the type itself was in the signature. Doh! But yes about the rest :)